# How do you compare strings in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I would assume comparing strings would be as easy as doing:

```
function withStrs(string memory a, string memory b) internal {
  if (a == b) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But doing so gives me an error `Operator == not compatible with types string memory and string memory`.

What's the right way?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can compare strings by hashing the packed encoding values of the string:

```
if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b))) {
  // do something
}
```

`keccak256` is a hashing function [supported by Solidity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions), and `abi.encodePacked()` encodes values via [the Application Binary Interface](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode).

Comment: Probably simple conversion to bytes (from [another answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4559/operator-not-compatible-with-type-string-storage-ref-and-literal-string#comment88932_11754)) is cheaper in terms of gas than `abi.encodePacked`. We have to check.